# Pass bot password when using LuisDialog

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need to pass the MS bot password dynamically when using LuisDialog.

I managed to do it successfully when handling system messages (see the else section in my code). But when using the Luis Diaog, since it's not using the connector object, I'm getting an exception.

I have the following code:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), m_botAppId, m_botAppPassword);

                if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
                {
// *how to pass the bot app password here???*

                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new IntentHandler(m_cmConnectionString, m_luisModelId, m_luisModelKey, m_tfsUser, m_tfsPassword));

                }
                else
                {
                    var reply = HandleSystemMessage(activity);
                    if (reply != null)
                    {
                        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
```

**Why do I need to pass the password dynamically?**
Because we do not want to store the secrets in a plaintext file and check it in. We also do not want to store it as plaintext in Azure.AppSettings since whoever has access to the same subscription can see the secret as plaintext there. 
Therefore I need to store the secret encrypted and need to decrypt it dynamically and then pass it to bot framework.

Comment: Why you need to pass the BotPassword to the LuisDialog? Are you not using the BotAuthentication attribute?

Comment: No I'm not using the attribute, I want to encrypt and decrypt it therefore need to pass it somehow

Comment: Encrypt / decrypt what? And why you cannot pass the password as a parameter of the dialog ctor?

Comment: I need to use the bot password somehow when sending the message back (Conversation.SendAsync) how do I do that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do and reasons you don't use the attribute, which is the way to go. I can check later if there are guidelines to override the auth method

Comment: Would appreciate that, thanks

Comment: This is the action filter that hanldes auth: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3a98a6b3d15962a57b5454bfb3f730d3588de3ef/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.NetFramework/BotAuthentication.cs... You might want to go over the code to understand a bit more what they are doing and see if you can extract something for your scenario (which is still not clear for me)

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I need to pass the password dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the AppSettings dynamically on the constructor.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[c_botAppPasswordSettingName] = m_botAppPassword;
```

This works. If anyone has another idea fell free to let me know.

Comment: Good! Please mark this question as answered to help other users to find this answer quickly

Comment: I can do that only in two days according to the site's limit. I will do that then.